# fast non-lock hashmap<Integer,Integer> or hashmap<Integer,Double> in Java?

Tags: hashmap, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I am looking for a fast implementation that support multiple threads for storing mapping from integers to integers or double. I have tried ConcurrentHashMap but are not impressed with the speedup factor. I also think that I could implement one by myself if it is not too bad.

Comment: You really ***really*** should not try to implement a concurrent implementation of hashmap yourself. ``ConcurrentHashMap``  really ***really*** is good at it.

Comment: Most likely, the bottleneck of your implementation does not come from ``ConcurrentHashMap`` but from other factors, such as disk reads, poor synchronization somewhere else ...

Comment: In my case it is pretty simple. Suppose I have an array of integers or doubles. I created once and will change the length or so. I would like to have multiple threads operating on the array. At each operation, a thread just change the value of the array. I'd like to have around 16-64 threads and the array is >64000 so I guess the collisions are not bad.

Comment: If you could point me to some implementation, it would be awesome.

Comment: Will the size of your array change through time?

Comment: Sorry for my misdescriptions. The array size does not change over time.  A thread only change the value of an element not multiple elements.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. An excessive number of poorly received questions that are off-topic will get you banned from asking questions, and you do not want that do you?

Answer (score 0):

Since the size is fixed, you might want to use an [`AtomicIntegerArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html) or an [`AtomicDoubleArray`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicDoubleArray.html) from Guava.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any other implementations ? I will compare them in whole to see which one is good for my purpose.